# Auto load scrolls infinitely showing the last item again and again

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm displaying 6 items from database by default.If the user scrolls down, then more items will be listed 2 items each time.This is the expected behavior.

But currently, the last item(6th) is shown again and again as the page scrolled down.I found that it's due to my sql query limits the result to the last id in the default 6 items. But even then it should not load anymore items if only 1 items matched the query but this loads infinitely as I scroll down.

So I need help in showing items AFTER the last id in the default 6 items and secondly, must not allow to scroll if all results are displayed.

Below is my code, please help.

script

```
$(function()
 {
var ID=$(".result_container:last").attr("id");
//alert(ID);
$(window).scroll(function(){

if  ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()){
 console.log($(document).height());

/*fetched the items from db**/

         $.ajax({
        dataType: "json",
        url: 'showAllTutor.php?action=get&last_msg_id='+ID,
        success: function(data){
        console.log(data.length);                               
        for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
         $('#showalltutor').append("<td><div class='result_container' id='"+data[i].postId+"'>show item here</div>");
        }
  }});
 }
);
```

PHP

```
 <?php
 $last_msg_id=$_GET['last_msg_id'];
 $action=$_GET['action'];

 if($last_msg_id=="")
 {
 ?>
 <?php
  $Tutor = new searchItems();
  $showAllTutor = $Tutor->showAllTutor($name);
  $json=array();
  foreach($showAllTutor as $key=>$value)
  {
     array_push($json,array("name"=>$value["name"],"subject"=>$value["subject"],"rate"=>$value['rate'],"dateposted"=>$value['dateposted'],"location"=>$value['location'],"contact"=>$value['contact'],"morning"=>$value['morning'],"afternoon"=>$value['afternoon'],"evening"=>$value['evening'],"postId"=>$value['postId'],"subid"=>$value['subid']));
  }
  ?>

  <?php
    }
    else
    {

     $sql="SELECT * FROM userinfo,posts WHERE userinfo.UUID = posts.UUID AND posts.postUUID = '$last_msg_id' LIMIT 2";
        $stmt =connection::$pdo->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute();
        $json=array();

        while($row = $stmt->fetch())
        {

          array_push($json,array("name"=>$row['name'],"subject"=>$row['subname'],"subid"=>$row['subID'],"rate"=>$row['pricing'],"dateposted"=>$row['datePosted'],"location"=>$row['location'],"contact"=>$row['phone'],"morning"=>$row['morning'],"afternoon"=>$row['afternoon'],"evening"=>$row['evening'],"postId"=>$row['postUUID']));
        }

    }

     echo json_encode($json);
    ?>

//the showAllTutor function as below:

public function showAllTutor()
    {

        $sql="SELECT * FROM userinfo,posts WHERE userinfo.UUID = posts.UUID LIMIT 6";
        $stmt =connection::$pdo->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute();
        $tutorAll=array();

        while($row = $stmt->fetch())
        {
          array_push($tutorAll,array("name"=>$row['name'],"subject"=>$row['subname'],"subid"=>$row['subID'],"rate"=>$row['pricing'],"dateposted"=>$row['datePosted'],"location"=>$row['location'],"contact"=>$row['phone'],"morning"=>$row['morning'],"afternoon"=>$row['afternoon'],"evening"=>$row['evening'],"postId"=>$row['postUUID']));
        }
        return $tutorAll;
    }
```

Comment: Why dont you try any jquery lazy load plugin to do this??

Comment: try printing your Array

Comment: @CY5, it prints all items if not last_msg_id given and prints only item which id is same with given last_msg_id.

Comment: so using limit 2 in query is meaningless when id is given

Comment: @CY5, that's the mistake..my query is wrong...The id is given to fetch items after the given id and show 2 items each time. BUt here only the item with given id is loaded infinitely.

Comment: @vani i think you will need to define an order to your table  like giving Auto Increment ID to column in your Table  
And then you can preform 
1.Get the Auto Increment ID of last_msgID
2.Run this query (what ever your AI column name is, I assume it as a_ID)
SELECT * FROM userinfo,posts WHERE userinfo.UUID = posts.UUID AND post.a_ID>5 LIMIT 2

Comment: @CY5, I changed my query as below,  $sql="SELECT * FROM userinfo,posts WHERE userinfo.UUID = posts.UUID AND posts.p_id > '$last_msg_id'";

Comment: Where $last_msg_id =6 ...I shows items after the id 6 but keep repeating. I tried using GROUP BY posts.p_id but still loading infinitely.

Comment: i think you forgot the LIMIT 2 i have specified above in query

Comment: LIMIT only shows 2 items after the last_msg_id and keep repeating.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88860/discussion-between-cy5-and-vani).

Answer (score 1):

If you didn't get answer yet try the below one

```
     $page_number=2;//You need to pass the page number while making ajax for first it will be 1.for second it will be 2 and so on

        $limit=2;//Number of records you need to fetch

        $offest=$limit*$page_number+$limit;

        $sql = "
            SELECT * 
            FROM userinfo,posts 
            WHERE userinfo.UUID = posts.UUID 
                LIMIT $offest,$limit";

        $stmt = connection::$pdo->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute();
$json=array('status'=>true,'data'=>array());
$count =$stmt->rowCount();
if($count>0){
 while($row = $stmt->fetch())
        {

          array_push($json['data'],array("name"=>$row['name'],"subject"=>$row['subname'],"subid"=>$row['subID'],"rate"=>$row['pricing'],"dateposted"=>$row['datePosted'],"location"=>$row['location'],"contact"=>$row['phone'],"morning"=>$row['morning'],"afternoon"=>$row['afternoon'],"evening"=>$row['evening'],"postId"=>$row['postUUID']));
        }
}else{
$json['status']=false;
}
```

You will need to restrict the ajax call once you get empty response by setting variable in javascript.So no more ajax call will sent to server.
Before making ajax check one conditionas follows

```
$(function()
 {
var is_more_result=true;//To check if there is any data by default keep true
var ID=$(".result_container:last").attr("id");
//alert(ID);
$(window).scroll(function(){

if  (($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()) &&  is_more_result){
 console.log($(document).height());

/*fetched the items from db**/

         $.ajax({
        dataType: "json",
        url: 'showAllTutor.php?action=get&last_msg_id='+ID,
        success: function(data){
        if(!data['status']){
          is_more_result=false;
            }                              
        for (i = 0; i < data['data'].length; i++) {
         $('#showalltutor').append("<td><div class='result_container' id='"+data[i].postId+"'>show item here</div>");
        }
  }});
 }
);
```

Comment: I'm using page here..All are loaded straight from db into a single page...I thibk the problem is with the jquery.The response is never 0. In my code, ajax call made each time page is scrolled..I think that's why it keep repeating the results..How do I control this plz